# What does this XML code mean?

Tags: xml, metadata

Here is the code and I am trying to figure out what the metadata is telling the server to do. I am a newbie to XML so your help will be greatly appreciated.

```
<forward:origin-server.host>origin-www.customer.com</forward:origin-server.host>
<forward:origin-server.dns-name.status>off</forward:origin-server.dns-name.status>
<match:arl.type value="cname">
    <forward:modify-host-header.value>%(AK_HOSTHEADER)</forward:modify-host-header.value>
    <forward:modify-host-header.status>on</forward:modify-host-header.status>
</match:arl.type>
```

Comment: That is some ugly misuse of XML.

Comment: Depends on what the receiver of the code is doing with it

Comment: Any ideas as to what exactly is each line about or the action it is trying to perform?

Comment: Well, if my program (that I just wrote) is reading it, it'll cause my computer to play the first few bars of *Thus Spoke Zarathustra*. What program are *you* feeding it to?

Answer (score 3):

XML means nothing in the absence of a specification for the particular XML vocabulary. You haven't given us such a specification, so in its absence, this XML fragment means nothing.

If you don't know where to find the specification, then looking at the namespace URIs to which the prefixes "forward" and "match" are bound may give a clue. You've left these namespace bindings out of your sample, which makes the question even harder to answer. If we could see the namespace URIs, then by convention they would often identify the designer/owner of this XML vocabulary, or at least enable us to google for further information.

Answer (score 0):

This is a configuration file for akamai cdn service.
It's configuring a service of reverse proxying.
But this xml is having just few lines, is not complete.